# Pass PHP Variable to Javascript function from Button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Here's what I got.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm(id)
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to duplicate this record?");
if (r==true)
  {
  window.open ("http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate=id","mywindow");
  }
else
  {
  alert("Record Not Duplicated.");
  }
}
</script>
```

then below that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
        $result = mysql_query($query);      

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

                $id = $row[0];
                $company = $row[3];
                $firstName = $row[4];
                $protection = $row[20];

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td width="120" align="middle"><font color="black"><b>' . $company . '</b></font></td>';
            echo '<td width="120" align="middle"><font color="black"><b>' . $firstName . '</b></font></td>';

            echo "<td width='120' align='middle'><a style='text-decoration: none;' href='http://domain.com/index.php?id=14&edit=" . $id . "'><span style='font-family:Helvetica; color:black;'>Edit</span></a>";
            echo "<td width='120' align='middle'><input type='button' onclick='show_confirm($id)' value='Duplicate' />";

            echo "</td>";               
            echo '</tr>';


        }
        ?>
```

The problem is this:

```
echo "<td width='120' align='middle'><input type='button' onclick='show_confirm($id)' value='Duplicate' />";
```

This is supposed to be a button where when the user clicks it, it says `"are you sure you want to duplicate?"` then if the use clicks yes, it to `http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate=(whatever the ID is)`

The problem is my variable (in php) `$id`, isn't getting passed to the javascript `window.open`. I need the `$id` from the row to be passed along in the javascript. I tried writing it, but it didn't work. Doesn't even see the variable. I've tried manually entering in `<?php echo $id; ?>` and that didn't work as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass the id, you must use the variable:

```
window.open ("http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate=" + id,"mywindow");
```

(you put it in the string)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open ("http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate=id","mywindow");
```

The URL is the string `"http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate=id"`.  You need to concat the variable to the string.  LIke this:

```
"http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate="+id
```

It should look like this:

```
window.open ("http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate="+id,"mywindow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the right concatenation operation by using the string concatenation operator in JavaScript which is the +
As you can see below all what you have to do is just attaching the id variable to your URL string.

`window.open ("http://domain.com/process.php?duplicate="+ id ,"mywindow");`